# Katalon studio - Call and Pass variable to another test case

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I want to call a test case and pass a variable of type webdriver and extenttest and his values to another testcase but i don’t have type “other” in the list of type and i can’t pass the value

[image]

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Comment: it works properly but i want  to call "New Test case " in another test case and pass driver , extent and extenttest

Comment: Try returning an object that contains driver, extent and extenttest.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define "extent" and "extenttest" variables (in "Variables" tab beside "Script" tab) in "test1" test case with the 'String' type and null value ('') as default. (Define them just in "test1")
2. Simply Call test case "New Test Case" wherever you want in "test1". 
   "Call test case" can add manually from "+Add" button or using this command in script mode:

`WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('New Test Case'), [:], FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)`